# Separate type when using generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-conversion, typescript-generics

I have an enam and an associated union type

```
export enum StorageTypeNames {
    User = "user",
    LoadSettings = "loadSettings",
    InitInfo = "isInit",
}

type StorageType = 
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.User, data: 'User' | 'Admin' | 'Amother' }
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.LoadSettings, data?: string[] }
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.InitInfo, data: boolean };
```

I use this association in my class:

```
export class StorageHelper {

  static getData<K extends StorageTypeNames>(type: K): **Extract<StorageType, { name: K }>['data'] | null;**

    static getData(type: StorageTypeNames) {
            let data: string | null = null;
            data = localStorage.getItem(type);
            return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
        }
}
```

I want to move the selected(boldet) part to a separate type, but there is a problem with generic **K**

When trying to move to a separate type, i get error:

```
type ExtractedType = Extract<StorageType, { name: K }>['data'] | null
//*error Cannot find name 'K'
```

The problem in  type variable "К"
[image: What i wnat to get]

please tell me how to make the selected part into a separate type and use it in other places:
simple ex.: [test playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=70&pln=24&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMo2gQwObAAqAnmMAHI6rADOcA3gFACQAqjcFHALxwBEyDlD4AaFgBkIOACYZgMGAEtEeOrz4AbKbPlKVNUSwCSiRTBMAzCD36KaJs4YC+jRjFLBM2KPiIebLAA+DHCIVMAAXF64BCRklNQ0AHTsnCJw0jgwOFEA5KlQuXDBuQCC0qjKRSWlqBAwABacRS7MwfSh4VFYMX7x4cmSMnIKyqrpmdkA-FE0MFBjANoAunCt7Z3U3d6+cRQDSQ7miFYTWTlwAEYQEBrAOIhrANyujKCQsHAAxho4NHQ9HwEAASwA0ZC4TEYcDgcyyii+cAIMAAIucADwAaQQIBgSGkAJ2sQ8CVoAD4ABTuMhRTEASiiAFFcT4vjB0YDdh50h0wls4NinGTFrlJjhcqtgigNBoXiw4UpEci0dkqR5tr09qSaHSGCxmMw7vAxbN5mNiqFkDKbNLZfrmGKbFovjgNJyCElkUY8ag1WQ6S8DcwoPJkFBHo6pnAAFIYADy5CSYBwUA4FLFuqitsDzBcThhrmpnmZ8xwbOA0j2NhLrPZ7r6wB5m0iArWwtF5wlFttQA)
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a generic type, but you forgot to make it generic

```
type ExtractedType<K> = Extract<StorageType, { name: K }>['data'] | null
//                ^^^ MAKE IT GENERIC
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMo2gQwObAAqAnmMAHI6rADOcA3gFACQAqjcFHALxwBEyDlD4AaFgBkIOACYZgMGAEtEeOrz4AbKbPlKVNUSwCSiRTBMAzCD36KaJs4YC+jRjFLBM2KPiIeeLAA+DHCIVMAAXF64BCRklNQ0AHTsnCJw0jgwOFEA5KlQuXDBuQCC0qjKRSWlqBAwABacRS7MwfSh4VFYMX7x4cmSMnIKyqrpmdkA-FE0MFBjANoAunCt7Z3U3d6+cRQDSQ7miFYTWTlwAEYQEBrAOIhrANyujKCQsHAAxho4NHQ9HwEAASwA0ZC4TBYcyyii+cAIMAAIucADwAaQQIBgSGkAJ2sQ8CVoAD4ABTuMhRdEASiiAFFsT4vjjpHsMSSXswYUp4YiUdkKR5tr09sSaDSGCxmHd4JMLnMFipiqFkBoNDYUOqucx5TYtF8cBpAb4koijDjUEKyDSdVB5MgoI89VM4AApDAAeXISTAOCgHDJ8slUS1Gi5Lhcbn8jPmOBZwDZHg5NljzJgqJNhLI6Q6YS2cExThJi1y8tyq2CYdcsrgADcbFngKDwZwzfIBTgyU2xQcCjTGAB6QdwOAAPSm0bIcBANnIEEQ5DVv0ud1RlOAEAs9ZJQ5Ho4njCAA)
That's all. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

`K` in `ExtractedType` is a generic type parameter. So you need to create a generic type to pass that `K` value to the `ExtractedType`.

`type ExtractedType<K> = Extract<StorageType, { name: K }>['data'] | null`

And use it in `getData` as `ExtractedType<K>`

Take a look at [Generics Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for more info